# Logout on Incorrect Token and Session Expiry

Tags: javascript, reactjs, axios, session-cookies

My current code has no automatic logout. So I attempted to implement auto-logout in two scenarios:

1. When the session expires.
2. When the access token is incorrect.

I am using an Axios interceptor to check authorization and log out if unauthorized. I am receiving an unauthorized (401) error in the network tab, but it is not triggering a logout. How can I make it work?

This is my code after adding the logout functionality:

```
import Cookies from 'universal-cookie';
import { format } from 'date-fns';
import APIServer from './URLs';
const axios = require('axios');
const authExpireAt = (expirySec) => {
  const date = new Date();
  return format(new Date(date.setSeconds(date.getSeconds() + parseInt(expirySec, 10) - 20)), 'yyyy/MM/dd hh:mm a');
};

const COOKIE_ATTR = {
  path: '/',
  maxAge: 31536000,
  // httpOnly: true,
  sameSite: true,
  secure: true,
};

const cookies = new Cookies();
const handleLogoutClick = () => {
  cookies.remove('access_token');
  cookies.remove('auth_expires');
  cookies.remove('refresh_token');
  window.location.pathname = '/';
};

// Add a request interceptor
axios.interceptors.request.use(
  (config) => {
    const accessToken = cookies.get('access_token');
    if (accessToken) {
      // eslint-disable-next-line no-param-reassign
      config.headers.Authorization = `Bearer ${accessToken}`;
    }
    return config;
  },
  (error) => Promise.reject(error),
);

// Add a response interceptor
axios.interceptors.response.use(
  (response) => response,
  (error) => {
    if (error.response && error.response.status === 401) {
      // Unauthorized, handle logout
      handleLogoutClick();
    }
    return Promise.reject(error);
  },
);

const GetToken = async () => {
  const refreshToken = cookies.get('refresh_token');
  const authExpires = cookies.get('auth_expires');

  if (new Date(authExpires).getTime() < new Date().getTime()) {
    const config = {
      method: 'get',
      url: `${APIServer}admins/token`,
      headers: {
        Authorization: `Bearer ${refreshToken}`,
      },
    };
    await axios(config)
      .then((response) => {
        const expiresAt = authExpireAt(response.headers.expires);
        cookies.set('access_token', response.data.result.accessToken, {
          ...COOKIE_ATTR,
        });
        cookies.set('refresh_token', response.data.result.refreshToken, {
          ...COOKIE_ATTR,
        });
        cookies.set('auth_expires', expiresAt, {
          ...COOKIE_ATTR,
        });
        return response.data.result.refreshToken;
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        console.log(error);

        // this is for session expired
        handleLogoutClick();
      });
  }
};
export default GetToken;
```